# Cannot implicitly convert type 'product

Tags: c#

I am getting 2 different error messages and I dont know where the problem is, I know it has something to do with the first 'product' & 'productModel.GetProduct (id);'.

My code is as follows:

```
Private void FillPage ()
{
if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace (Request.QueryString ["id"]))
{
   int id = Convert.ToInt32 (Request.QueryString [id]);
   ProductModel productModel = new ProductModel ();
   Product product = ProductModel. GetProduct (id);
```

The last line of code contains the issue. The errors I am getting are:

> Product error
>
> The type 'Product' in F:\Product.aspx' conflicts with the imported
> type 'Product' in 'App_Code.gmsjomg_, Version=0.0.0.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. Using the type defined in
> F:\Product.aspx'.
>
> ProductModel.GetProduct (id) error
>
> Cannot implicitly convert type 'Product [F:\App_Code\Model.cs (25)' to
> 'Product [F:\Product.aspx (12)]'

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I'm completely lost with these errors I cannot seem to get around them. Thanks

Comment: Are there two different `Product` classes defined? That's what the error message makes it sound like. Make sure that the `Product` class you use when defining the `product` variable is the same as the return type of `GetProduct`.

Comment: Are you sure the second call to Request.QueryString[id] should not be ["id"] ??

Comment: The second call to request is ["id"], sorry about that

Comment: Go to the definition of `ProductModel.GetProduct()` and check the complete namespace for what it returns. Compare that to the namespace defined in the definition of your `Product` class on the left of the equal sign. As @pushasha said, it sounds like you have two different `Product` classes and it's trying to convert one to the other... "The type `Product` conflicts with the imported type `Product`"

Comment: Can you post the code for the `Product` and `ProductModel` classes?

Comment: It won't let me post the code due to it being too many characters

Comment: public Product GetProduct(int id)
    {
        try
        {
            using (StaircaseDBEntities db = new StaircaseDBEntities())
            {
                Product product = db.Products.Find(id);
                return product;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }